# Something happened last week, but not this week mysql query

Tags: mysql

Lets say I had a table with data like this...

```
[date of event] [event type]
1/1             A
1/1             B
1/3             A
1/4             B
1/7             B
1/7             A
1/15            A
```

and today was 1/15

is there a way to see if an event happened last week, but not this week?

For instance, 'A' happened both this week and last week (1/15 and 1/7)... however 'B' only happened last week (1/7 only). Ideally I would be able to get the answer to such a query as 'B'.

I've spent a few days on this, and i'm completely stuck. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What does "last week" mean? between 7 and 14 days ago, or the Monday-Sunday including the date 7 days ago, or ???

Comment: fair question. It could be between two datetimes or like a date_sub(interval 7 day). In my mind it would be the last 7 days from today (so the latter of the two), but i'm not picky and i'm more looking for how to do the other part. None the less thanks for your question.

Comment: I'm glad that you seem to have solved you problem. But, as an aside, according to your preferred definition of 'last week', I find the question misleading. There was no event on the 8th, so 'A' didn't happen 'both this week and last week'!

Comment: I think you may have got me there on a technical note. Well played!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy to solve via a left join of suitable views (subqueries):

```
select @start_a:='2019-01-02';
select @end_a:='2019-01-08';
select @start_b:='2019-01-09';
select @end_b:='2019-01-15';
-- these could be e.g. DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)

SELECT DISTINCT A.event_type
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT event_type
  FROM table_name
  WHERE date_of_event>=@start_a AND date_of_event<=@end_a
) AS A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT event_type
  FROM table_name
  WHERE date_of_event>=@start_b AND date_of_event<=@end_b
) AS B
ON A.event_type=B.event_type
WHERE B.event_type IS NULL
;
```

Explanation: We select all of the week's events into A, all of the comparison week's events into B. Then we select those rows from A, that have no counterpart in the comparison week.

Comment: This looks like a lot of query.

Comment: @Strawberry Writing it very readably makes it longer of course.

Comment: This is perfect. I am curious: can the 'from table_name' be the same throughout the query?

Comment: @returntrue There is only one table in your question!

Comment: @EugenRieck yep, I was just double checking that the same one table can be used in that way. It sounds like it can, thanks again for your time I appreciate it.

Comment: @returntrue The idea is to create two views into the same table, that look like two different tables - one for the current week, the other for the comparison week. We can join those as if they were indeed different tables.

Answer (score 1):

If (significantly) less typing (and/or improved performance) is your thing, then you might consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(dt DATE NOT NULL
,event_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(dt,event_type)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2019-01-01','A'),
('2019-01-01','B'),
('2019-01-03','A'),
('2019-01-04','B'),
('2019-01-07','B'),
('2019-01-07','A'),
('2019-01-15','A');
```

So, let's find events that *did* repeat...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.event_type = x.event_type
            AND y.dt = '2019-01-15'
          WHERE x.dt BETWEEN '2019-01-15' - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND '2019-01-15' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
+------------+------------+
| dt         | event_type |
+------------+------------+
| 2019-01-01 | A          |
| 2019-01-03 | A          |
| 2019-01-07 | A          |
+------------+------------+
```

...and then the inverse of that...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.event_type 
           FROM my_table x 

           LEFT

           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.event_type = x.event_type
            AND y.dt = '2019-01-15'
          WHERE x.dt BETWEEN '2019-01-15' - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND '2019-01-15' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
            AND y.dt IS NULL;
+------------+
| event_type |
+------------+
| B          |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Strawberry! I am curious, do you know if this is any faster or slower than the other submitted answer. Great answer and thanks again!

Comment: On a data set of 100,000 rows (dense data - i.e. lots of events over very few dates), my query takes 0.19 secs vs the other solution, which takes 49.1 secs - so roughly 250 times faster.